# Error when no object data on JSON

Tags: c#, json, gridview, uwp

I have the following JSON:
[image: JSON]

JSON:

```html
data: [
{
geo: {
lat: -7.328805,
lng: 112.696606
},
id: 337417,
title: "Omapukis, UD",
address: "Kebraon Manis Barat BJ/01, Surabaya, Jawa Timur, 60222, Indonesia",
phone: "+6285748393379",
rating: 5,
classifieds: [ ],
image_url: "http://indonesia-product.com/custom/domain_1/image_files/sitemgr_photo_1303.jpg",
type: "listing"
},
{
id: 8,
title: "Traditional Food "Pukis", Surabaya SME Goes To Online",
author: "",
publication_date: "2017-04-11T00:00:00+0700",
rating: 0,
image_url: "http://indonesia-product.com/custom/domain_1/image_files/sitemgr_photo_1267.jpg",
type: "article"
}
]
}
```

At first the JSON data has "geo" object that contains the "lat" and "lng" data, while the second JSON data does not have a "geo" object.
JSON is displayed on the gridview. If I use the code below, then if they do not have a "geo" object, then the application can not run.

Code:

```
JsonObject groupObject2 = groupValue1.GetObject();

                                JsonObject jsonGeo = groupObject2["geo"].GetObject();
                                JsonObject groupObject3 = jsonGeo.GetObject();
                                double lat = groupObject3["lat"].GetNumber();
                                double lng = groupObject3["lng"].GetNumber();
```

ANd I tried the code below:

Code:

```
JsonObject groupObject2 = groupValue1.GetObject();

                                    JsonObject jsonGeo = groupObject2.ContainsKey("geo") && groupObject2["geo"] != null ? groupObject2["geo"].GetObject() : object.Equals(null, null);
                                    JsonObject groupObject3 = jsonGeo.GetObject();
                                    double lat = groupObject3.ContainsKey("lat") && groupObject3["lat"] != null ? groupObject3["lat"].GetNumber() : double.NaN;
                                    double lng = groupObject3.ContainsKey("lng") && groupObject3["lng"] != null ? groupObject3["lng"].GetNumber() : double.NaN;
```

On

```
JsonObject jsonGeo = groupObject2.ContainsKey("geo") && groupObject2["geo"] != null ? groupObject2["geo"].GetObject() : object.Equals(null, null);
```

error message appears:

```
Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject' and 'bool'
```

How can I fix when the data in JSON does not have a "geo" object?

Comment: Put this in bracket `groupObject2.ContainsKey("geo") && groupObject2["geo"] != null`, as follows
`(groupObject2.ContainsKey("geo") && groupObject2["geo"] != null)`

Comment: Do one more favor please paste json as code snippet not image, its easy to use it as a code

Comment: I have added the json in my question (link: http://indonesia-product.com/api/v1/results.json?q=omapukis&module=listings&page=1&token=3f63-dc43-c8d5-eb45-8cbf-b72d-9d98-800f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you are making the check your code needs to be like this, inside the bracket:

`(groupObject2.ContainsKey("geo") && groupObject2["geo"] != null)`

> Why ?

Since this is how you make it single boolean condition, else its `&&` between a boolean `groupObject2.ContainsKey("geo")` and a `JsonObject` like `groupObject2["geo"] != null ? groupObject2["geo"].GetObject() : object.Equals(null, null)`, which is not valid and compiler will lead to an expected error

**Edit1:**

Code has fundamental mistake, as check in [source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4oRSWSS0hKDa09MV3RlLXhhTFk/view), following are important examples:

1. Incorrect - `JsonObject jsonGeo = (groupObject2.ContainsKey("geo") && groupObject2["geo"] != null);`, as its assigning `JsonObject` to a `Boolean`, which compiler is complaining, correct version would be something like:
   `JsonObject jsonGeo = (groupObject2.ContainsKey("geo") && groupObject2["geo"] != null) ? groupObject2["geo"].GetObject() : null`

You have made a similar update at multiple places, ideally `boolean` condition is to check the existence of a value, if true then assignment is made, this has less to do with Json, more with your C# understanding.

**Edit2:**

Why I was suggestion `Json.Net`, since, it is much easy to work with Typed objects, check out an example of your code, everything is filled in a `wrapper` object, is it thus easy to work with the objects

```
void Main()
{
    string jsonText1 = "{\"data\":[{\"geo\":{\"lat\":-7.328805,\"lng\":112.696606},\"id\":337417,\"title\":\"Omapukis, UD\",\"address\":\"Kebraon Manis Barat BJ/01, Surabaya, Jawa Timur, 60222, Indonesia\",\"phone\":\"+6285748393379\",\"rating\":5,\"classifieds\":[],\"image_url\":\"http://indonesia-product.com/custom/domain_1/image_files/sitemgr_photo_1303.jpg\",\"type\":\"listing\"},{\"id\":8,\"title\":\"Traditional Food Pukis, Surabaya SME Goes To Online\",\"author\":\"\",\"publication_date\":\"2017-04-11T00:00:00+0700\",\"rating\":0,\"image_url\":\"http://indonesia-product.com/custom/domain_1/image_files/sitemgr_photo_1267.jpg\",\"type\":\"article\"}]}";

    var wrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(jsonText1);

    // print wrapper object
}

public class Wrapper
{
    public List<Data> data { get; set;}
}

public class Data
{
    public Geo geo { get; set;}

    public int Id { get; set;}

    public string Title { get; set;}

    public string Address { get; set;}

    public string Phone { get; set;}

    public int Rating { get; set;}

    public string ImageUrl { get; set;}

    public string Type { get; set;}
}

public class Geo
{
    public double lat { get; set;}

    public double lng { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: i put inside the brancket and display error messsage : Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject'

Comment: Please paste the code what you have done, as per error you are assigning boolean to JsonObject, which is incorrect

Comment: Here is the code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4oRSWSS0hKDa09MV3RlLXhhTFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide the Json too, so that it can be tested

Comment: Which Json serializer are you using Newtonsoft (Json.Net) ?

Comment: I using Windows.Data.Json;

Comment: Would you be Ok using [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com), which is much better and popular library for Json

Comment: how to handle my problem?

Comment: Check my Edits, you need to learn some C# to move beyond a specific point

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to figure out what the correct behaviour for your application is when there's no `geo` data available. For example, if you're writing an application to display locations on a map, you might choose to ignore all the listings without a location. On the other hand, if you're showing the locations in a list, you might just not display a map for the ones with no `geo` data.

Ultimately, I think this is a business decision, meaning one that will be determined by business needs or by the planned features for whatever you're writing.

Comment: no, I want to overcome JSON does not have a "geo" object so that the application is not an error. When JSON does not have a "geo" object, then no need to display "lat" and "lng" data. Meanwhile, when JSON has "geo" object, it is necessary to display the "lat" and "lng" data. Note: JSON has been provided, so just need to display JSON data in the gridview.